# Problems reading Java Process output

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to run a process within my Java code and read the output from this process. The problem is that when I run the process the code just hangs.

The command I am trying to run is:
RNAplex < query.fasta

Where query.fasta is the file containing the information I want RNAplex to process.

when I run this in the terminal I get the following output:

> .((.((.((.((.&)).)).)).)).   7,19  :   1,12  (-3.30) i:18,j:1 <-3.40>
>
> .((((((.((.&)).)))))).   4,14  :   1,10  (-14.30) i:13,j:1 <-14.40>

After this output, the process terminates.

The code I'm using to run is the following:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RNAplex < query.fasta");

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    p.waitFor();
    
    String msg;
    while ((msg = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
```

Do you have any idea as to why there is no output from the process? I have tested it with other commands such as:

> free -g

The code works and I am able to read the output from this:

```
                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache      available
 Mem:            125          43          41           0          40          81
 Swap:           127           0         127
```

Comment: What means `is not working`? Can you describe what is wrong

Comment: @Jens Sorry! it was a little ambiguous I admit. I have reworded it. The problem is that there is no output from the process and I assume that it's because it doesn't terminate. I know that it starts because I can see the process running.

Comment: You have to use `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()` to get the output

Comment: @Jens I will try this. It's strange how it works with the free command though? I have added the java console output from this to the bottom of the question.

Comment: mybe because free doensnt read anything from stdin

Comment: @Jens I think the issue was with the < as I just tried it with the following command: cat query.fasta | RNAplex and I am able to get the output with the above code

Comment: Actually, nevermind. It just returns the input to the process rather than the output from the process.